# Dialog in the camera activity after a picture has been taken

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I want to use the standard camera app in android to take a picture in my app. The thing is, after the picture has been taken, I do not want to go back immediately to my app. Instead, I would like an option to be presented to the user asking him/her if the picture they have just taken is okay. If not, then do not go back to the app, instead, re-run the camera activity.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try Like THis :

```
 public void TakeFromCamera(View view) {

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(requestCode){

    case CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST:

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {

                         //  Add the code for the dialogBox
        }
        break;

    }
}
```